# When a string start differ from another?

Tags: php, mysql, string, select

I have in a database MySQL a column containing a **product-name** with his respective **color**

**e.g.**

```
desk GM dark blue
desk GM dark green
desk GM yellow
desk GM pink
desk GM yellow
desk HY sad blue
desk HY yellow
desk bull red
desk bull happy green
```

The products would be `desk GM`, `desk HY` and `desk bull` and the colors would be

```
 - dark blue
 - dark green
 - pink
 - yellow
 - sad blue
 - red
 - happy green
```

Note that the color shouldn't be replicated more than once, neither the products.

---

I didn't start to code because I don't have a clue where to begin (besides getting the list from my SQL in a file and reading it through a while).

I was thinking in a way to distinct them, for instance, after the 2 position (using a `explode` function) would start the color name. But, there are names like `Home Theather Eagle` and `Center Table America` and others like `Hack 5000` and `Hack Angel`.

**So, my question is:** *Is there a way, besides creating manually an array of `products` to remove them from each string result?*

*Example of what I mean by the text from above. Consider that `$products` was feed manually by me.*

```
foreach($products as $product) {
    if (strpos($products, $row_result_from_sql) !== false) {
        str_replace($products, "", $row_result_from_sql);
    }
}
```

Comment: So you have the product and color stored as one string, and you want to remove the color part from the string? Is that right?

Comment: @MarkM yes, that is quite precise of what I want. Glad you understood =)

Comment: But I'm 90% sure that this is impossible to do ... I posted here more to cleanse my conscience.

Comment: Is the list of colors fixed? Meaning it will always be one of those 7 that you listed, or are you dealing with a huge/unknown array of possible colors?

Comment: If the Colors list is small, perhaps you can use them in an array to differentiate product and color.

Comment: I'm trying to get a *column* `description` from the *table* `product` *database* `dbA` and create in the *database* `dbB` one table containing **all** colors and another containing **all** products, then another to create a relationship betwenn them. So 3 tables from 1 column

Comment: The problem is that not all of the tuples contain colors, like Home Theater Eagle and Center Table America. So you're right, this would be nearly impossible to do, sans creating an array of colors that each row could be checked against - "here is a row, do any of these colors exist in this row? if so, do what you gotta' do, if not, do something else you have to do"

Comment: *off-topic* Funny fact... My playlist started play [AC/DC - Highway to Hell](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qKggnBh2Mdw&feature=kp) ... I think this is a sign ... T_T

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you are dealing with, you might be able to do it like this:

```
$colors = array(
    'dark blue', 
    'dark green', 
    'pink', 
    'yellow', 
    'sad blue',
    'red',
    'happy green'
);

$products = array(
    'desk GM dark blue',
    'desk GM dark green',
    'desk GM yellow',
    'desk GM pink',
    'desk GM yellow',
    'desk HY sad blue',
    'desk HY yellow',
    'desk bull red',
    'desk bull happy green'
);

foreach ($products as $i=>$product) 
    foreach ($colors as $color) 
        if (strpos($product, $color) !== false)
            $products[$i] = str_replace($color, '', $products[$i]);

print_r($products);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => desk GM 
    [1] => desk GM 
    [2] => desk GM 
    [3] => desk GM 
    [4] => desk GM 
    [5] => desk HY 
    [6] => desk HY 
    [7] => desk bull 
    [8] => desk bull 
)
```

Comment: The problem is that he has to extract a column from a database and then divide them up into their respective arrays for insertion into other tables.

Comment: This way I would have to have a previous list of products or colors to run that foreach

Comment: Ya I'm reading the newest comments and I see that this would not work. Without knowing either the possible colors or products, I don't see how this could be done.

Comment: `strpos()` doesn't return `-1`. It returns FALSE.

Comment: @rudie Yes you're right, not sure what I was thinking. Thanks I changed it.

Answer (score 0):

If tables are represented for only `2 words`. You can use:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('fieldname',' ', 2) from tableName;
```

Comment: As I pointed in the question. `"I was thinking in a way to distinct them, for instance, after the 2 position (using a explode function) would start the color name. But, there are names like Home Theather Eagle and Center Table America and others like Hack 5000 and Hack Angel."`

Comment: in this case only color mapping will help you like   
answered recomended

Answer (score 0):

if you have all the colours in a known colour[] array in your code,

You could read the database, and for each record
if any entry in colour[] is found in the product field text of each record,

replace the colour text with ""
then, save the (modified)product text into a product[] array.

You did not mention if duplicate product names (sans the colour info) need to be unique.
If so, you could check if the (modified)product text is already in the array, and if not, add it as a new entry in the array.

Comment: As I said in the question. **No I don't have** any array containing the colors nor the products